# Background image opacity - Tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a background image and I am trying to give it a background opacity but I cannot to get it to work. I am using tailwind css.

```
   <div className="text-mainText font-Montserrat bg-main-star-background sm:bg-10 sm:bg-right-22 bg-right-10 bg-no-repeat bg-2 sm:bg-opactity-0">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `bg-opacity-x` in Tailwind only works with background colors and not with background images.

For example, that will totally work :

```html
<div class="h-full w-full min-h-screen bg-sky-600 bg-opacity-25"></div>
```

But this wouldn't :

```html
<div style="background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542995470-870e12e7e14f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80')"
     class="h-full w-full min-h-screen bg-opacity-25"></div>
```

What you could do is **adding a linear gradient** above your background-image matching your bg colors :

```html
<div style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(9, 148, 143, 0.9), rgba(9, 148, 143, 0.9)), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542995470-870e12e7e14f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80')" class="h-full w-full min-h-screen"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. The linear-gradient worked for me!

Comment: Glad it did! ;) Happy coding!